# join/merge tidy timeseries data r

Tags: r, join, time-series, tidyr

I am wondering about the proper/best way to join timeseries data when applying the principals of tidy data.

The problem is that the join functions join all rows for which there is a match. This results in a massive expansion of the number of rows in the joined data set.

So for example, if i have two tidy data sets with time series:

```
df1 <- data.frame(location = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                  time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  color = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
df2 <- data.frame(location = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                  time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  intensity = c(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

and i look to left_join them, i get a huge dataframe as all rows with location 1 get captured:

```
> left_join(df1, df2, by = "location")
   location time.x color time.y intensity
1         1      1     1      1         8
2         1      1     1      2         7
3         1      1     1      3         6
4         1      1     1      4         5
5         1      2     2      1         8
6         1      2     2      2         7
7         1      2     2      3         6
8         1      2     2      4         5
9         1      3     3      1         8
10        1      3     3      2         7
11        1      3     3      3         6
12        1      3     3      4         5
13        1      4     4      1         8
14        1      4     4      2         7
15        1      4     4      3         6
16        1      4     4      4         5
17        2      1     5      1         4
18        2      1     5      2         3
19        2      1     5      3         2
20        2      1     5      4         1
21        2      2     6      1         4
22        2      2     6      2         3
23        2      2     6      3         2
24        2      2     6      4         1
25        2      3     7      1         4
26        2      3     7      2         3
27        2      3     7      3         2
28        2      3     7      4         1
29        2      4     8      1         4
30        2      4     8      2         3
31        2      4     8      3         2
32        2      4     8      4         1
```

What i want is:

```
 location time color intensity
1        1    1     1         8
2        1    2     2         7
3        1    3     3         6
4        1    4     4         5
5        2    1     5         4
6        2    2     6         3
7        2    3     7         2
8        2    4     8         1
```

How can i join this tidy data by "location"? Do i have to first `spread()` the data, `join()` and then `gather()`. That solution seems like it will be very laborious if i have lots of timesteps and lots of variables.

Given how common timeseries data is and the importance of tidy data, i am assuming there is a simple way to manage this. Sorry if i am overlooking something simple.

Comment: It looks like you want to join by both `location` and `time`.  Is that right?

Comment: To join by location and time, try: `left_join(df1, df2, by = c("location", "time"))`

Comment: Yes, joining by multiple variable works. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` function might be what you need here:

```
> merge(df1, df2)
location time color intensity
1        1    1     1         8
2        1    2     2         7
3        1    3     3         6
4        1    4     4         5
5        2    1     5         4
6        2    2     6         3
7        2    3     7         2
8        2    4     8         1
```

Comment: Merge also works. In the df (as in this example) variable names have to be identical. Thanks very much.